# How do I display an image when a user hovers over a link using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I've got a list of products.

```
<ul>
<li><a href="chair.php">CHAIR</a></li>
<li><a href="table.php">TABLE</a></li>
<li><a href="sofa.php">SOFA</a></li>
<li><a href="bookshelf.php">BOOKSHELF</a></li>
<ul>
```

On mouseover I want to display a thumbnail image of the product in a div #preview.

I don't want to hardcode the jquery for each image. Rather I'd like to write JQuery that would grab the image location and insert into the DOM. I have no idea how I would mark up the HTML to include the image location. Any ideas?

Comment: @you want to show a chair one mouseover of chair and table picture on mouseover of table??

Comment: it should be pretty easy , if nobody answers your question , i will reply after my dinner hmmm

Comment: @but keep in mind that you need to have some mapping for each href to image or store a hidden span with image path for each object

Comment: Check this post-http://codegena.com/image-link-preview-on-hover/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd suggest using the [new HTML5 data attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes), like so:

```
<a href="chair.php" data-thumbnail-src="chair.jpg">CHAIR</a>
```

Then you could set up the jQuery code as follows:

```
$(function () {
    var $preview = $("#preview");

    $("ul#products a").hover(function () {
        $preview.attr("src", $(this).attr("data-thumbnail-src"));
    }, function () {
        $preview.attr("src", "");
    });
});
```

In jQuery 1.4.3 and higher, I believe `$(this).data("thumbnail-src")` will also work.

Comment: it won't support all browsers , as it is HTML5

Comment: Actually, HTML5 is specifically designed to be backward-compatible; all browsers since Netscape 1.0 recognize new custom attributes. If he tried to use the `dataset` DOM property, that wouldn't work in older browsers; however, using jQuery's `attr` or `data` methods works just fine.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. I had no idea about the custom data tag. I was tempted to use a "rel" tag, but that just didn't feel right.

Answer (score 2):

its is old , but i got here with google search .
i believe the best solution would be this : http://james.padolsey.com/demos/imgPreview/full/

Comment: Unfortunately the download link is dead now.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this is a decent solution. Im using the [JQuery Metadata plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-metadata)

Here is the stuff live : http://jsfiddle.net/giddygeek/VqL65/14/

**Html:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://github.com/jquery/jquery-metadata/raw/master/jquery.metadata.js"></script>
<ul class="pics">
<li class="pic {url:'chair.jpg'}">
    <a href="chair.php">CHAIR</a></li>
<li class="pic {url:'table.jpg'}">
    <a href="table.php">TABLE</a></li>
<li>
    <a href="sofa.php">SOFA</a></li>
<li>
    <a href="bookshelf.php">BOOKSHELF</a></li>
<ul>
<div id="preview">
<img src="" />
<div/>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
       $("ul.pics li").hover(
           function()
           {//on hover over
              var data = $(this).metadata();//get the metadata 
               if(data.url) {//check if it exists
                   $("#preview img").attr("src",data.url)//set the url to it
               }

           },
           function()
           {//on hover OUT
               $("#preview img").attr("src","");//set the img src to nothing
           }
           );
    }
);
```

**Notes:**

- [Ive heard this is W3C compliant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182630/jquery-tips-and-tricks/504776#504776) and might be compatible with Html5
- Do add a class for each `<li>` named `pic {url:'something'}`.
- Set the url to your favorite picture.
- In the JQuery, the hover out sets the img src to nothing-> `""`. Here you should set it to a NONE pic or do something else.
- Oh and [download the metadata plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-metadata) (I used a raw link from github)

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. This definitely works, but the other answer has the advantage of not needing a plugin. :)

Comment: @pole true. Actually while answering I thought using an HTML5 attribute would not be fully supported or would cause problems. Then I came across this post later: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355082/is-html-5-supported-by-all-the-main-browsers