# Grab <li> 'data-thumbnail-src' on hover and display <img> next to cursor

Tags: html, jquery, css

I'm working with an `<ol>` containing multiple `<li>` items.

All the `<li>` items have unique `data-thumbnail-src` information:

```
<li data-thumbnail-src="image_01.jpg">Item 01</li>
<li data-thumbnail-src="image_02.jpg">Item 02</li>
<li data-thumbnail-src="image_03.jpg">Item 03</li>
```

With jQuery I am trying to grab the 'data-thumbnail-src' on `<li>` hover.

I am then trying to display the image from the 'data' next to the cursor.

---

The jQuery code [found here](https://learningjquery.com/2011/10/how-to-add-trailing-image-to-mouse-cursor-using-jquery) seems to show an image next to the cursor:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).mousemove(function(e){
        $('#thumbnail').offset({left:e.pageX,top:e.pageY+20});    
    });
});
```

---

The jQuery code [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363902/how-do-i-display-an-image-when-a-user-hovers-over-a-link-using-jquery) seems to grab the data from the 'data-thumbnail-src':

```
$(function () {
    var $preview = $("#preview");

    $("ul#products a").hover(function () {
        $preview.attr("src", $(this).attr("data-thumbnail-src"));
    }, function () {
        $preview.attr("src", "");
    });
});
```

---

I've tried to combine the two bits of code, without succes.

I very much could do with a push in the right direction.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).mousemove(function(e){
        $('#preview').offset({left:e.pageX,top:e.pageY+20});    
    });
});

$(function () {
    var $preview = $("#preview");

    $("li").hover(function () {
        $preview.attr("src", $(this).attr("data-thumbnail-src"));
    }, function () {
        $preview.attr("src", "");
    });
});
```

```css
#preview {
  position: absolute;
  width:100px;
  height:100px
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li data-thumbnail-src="image_01.jpg">Item 01</li>
<li data-thumbnail-src="image_02.jpg">Item 02</li>
<li data-thumbnail-src="image_03.jpg">Item 03</li>
```

---

**Update**

As pointed out in the comments, and `img` tag was missing in the HTML code. I have added `<img id="preview">` following the examples by @freedomn-m and @CBroe in the comments below.

Comment: Looks like about the only thing that is missing, is an actual `img` element with the ID `preview` ...?

Comment: What do you mean, "I was hoping"? The current code does no such thing.

Comment: `var $preview = $("#preview");` -> `#preview` references an element with `id=preview`.  If there's no such element, the css does nothing and the jquery returns a collection with length 0.  Elements are not automagically generated just because you reference them in the CSS (what sort of element should #preview be?  div / input / select / etc.   You can create the element with jquery, but no need, just add `<img id="preview">` into your html.

Comment: Your code with an `img` tag (and a show/hide when not hovering):  https://jsfiddle.net/013e9dap/1/

Comment: Recommendation: rather than `$(this).attr("data-thumbnail-src")` use `$(this).data("thumbnail-src")` - then the attr will be cached so it doesn't need to be read from the DOM each time (which is relatively slow) - micro optimisation in this case, but a good practice/habit

Comment: To add the img, eg if you're going down a plugin route and the img might not exist, do something like:  `if ($("#preview").length === 0) $("<img id='preview' />").appendTo("body");`

Comment: Thanks, it's midnight now where I am living however I'll try all these first thing tomorrow.

Comment: @cbroe I was under the impression the code at the moment was creating the img element instead of me having all the img elements for each <li> hover hard coded in the html. I'm pretty new to jQuery/javascript

Comment: @freedomn-m so you're saying '$(this).attr("data-thumbnail-src")' can be replaced with $(this).data("thumbnail-src")? Do I also change the <li> elements from 'data-thumbnail-src' to just 'thumbnail-src' ?

Comment: _"instead of me having all the img elements for each <li> hover hard coded in the html"_ - no one said anything about _that_. The code tries to assign the dynamic image URL from the hovered LI, to an already existing image element - this needs _one_ image element, but that will not come into existence magically on its own. You need to either have an `img` element with the id `preview ` already in your document - or the JS will have to _create_ it.

Comment: *do I also change* - no.   `.data("xx")` gets the value from attribute `data-xx`.   `<div data-abc="123">` -> `$("div").data("abc") === "123"`    See how `.data(` removes the `data-` prefix from the attribute.

Comment: *instead of me having all the img elements for each <li>* - no you have *one* `<img id="preview">` which `$("#preview")` will then reference and `#preview` css will style.   See this fiddle for an example: https://jsfiddle.net/013e9dap/1