# is html 5 compatible with all commonly used browsers?

Tags: html

is html 5 compatible with all commonly used browsers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is HTML 5 supported by all the main browsers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355082/is-html-5-supported-by-all-the-main-browsers)

Answer (score 1):

Most of the main browsers: Firefox, Safari and Opera support the main features of HTML5 such as the new structural elements. Then you have Internet Explorer 8, which doesn't support anything at all but this can be fixed using the HTML5 shiv script (which also works for IE6 and 7). Like the other main browers, IE9 supports some HTML5 features.

Comment: Seriously, what I said is correct and valid. Why was it voted down?

Comment: And here we go again, the brave down-voters who neglect to leave a comment.

Comment: +1 to get you back at 0 vote. Note that IE9 does not support every feature from HTML5. :)

Comment: Ha thanks. Yes, I'm aware of that, but neither do the other browsers!

Answer (score 0):

It's not. Only Chrome and Safari, yet supports all of features. Anyway use all HTML5&CSS3 elements, but with Modernizer.js, it will keep everything working while all other browsers will ones get html5 etc. to work in them :)

There is another point of using it: as soon as most web-designers will be using it, all browsers will follow :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link (http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/html5.html) to a list of which browsers support html5

All the latest popular browsers support it to some degree (however small in IE). However your website shouldn't depend on it at the moment, and always neatly fallback to something else for browsers that don't support html5

Comment: Small in IE? You mean non-existent! (except in IE9 - when it's finished)

Answer (score 0):

See [When can I use...](http://caniuse.com/#cats=HTML5) for compatibility tables for support of HTML5 in desktop and mobile browsers. If you want to use HTML5 for one of your projects, you'll have to [detect support for individual HTML5 features](http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html) in JS.

Answer (score 0):

You can access following link from any of the browser.

http://html5test.com/

This link will explain :- how well does your browser support HTML5?

Answer (score -1):

No and won't be for quite some times since the Html 5 spec is nowhere near finalized and is always in a state of flux (even those specs that browser vendors are working on).

Comment: It's a lot more stable than you think.